# Eureka Forms Dynamically add values to options

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, eureka-forms

I'm trying to add values from a dictionary to the options in an ActionSheetRow. This is the dictionary.

```
"Options": [
    {
      "1": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "2": "No"
    }
  ]

  // form
  form +++ Section("Section1")
   <<< ActionSheetRow<String>() {
                $0.tag = values.key
                $0.title = values.key
                $0.options = []
                for test in values.options! {
                  // returns Options values.
                  print([test.values])
                 }
        }
```

I can print out my dictionary fine but the problem is trying to add add the values inside the dictionary to a selectable list. E.g "yes" or "no" options.

Answer (score 1):

Inside this loop add values to sheet options,

```
for test in values.options! {
      $0.options.append(test.values.first!)
       // returns Options values.
       print([test.values])
  }
```

Comment: I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary<String, String>.Values' to expected argument type 'String'" So using "$0.options?.append(contentsOf: selectableOptions.values)" has seemed to have fixed it. Not sure if it's the best practice

Comment: It’s fine to append like this. I wanted to give you a pointer. I hope it helped